# total area between two sets of x and y-coordinates [r]

Tags: r

I've got a series of x and y-coordinates for two trajectories, and now I'd like to be able to calculate the area of the space between the lines.

Here's a real example of what I'm working with, trying to capture the deviation from the ball line that the user does:

[image: Real example]

I would generally speaking like to capture how much the user's line deviates from the ball's line. The way I'd like to capture this is the area between the two lines (although arguably the best way would be to capture the minimum distance from the ball line for every point of the user's line).

I've got code that captures the area with simple examples:

```
example.matrix = matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,  2,5,3,5,3,5,2,  2,2,4,6,4,2,2),nrow = 7)
example.plot.data = data.frame(x = rep(example.matrix[,1],2),
                 ball_user = c(rep("user",length(example.matrix[,2])),
                               rep("ball",length(example.matrix[,3]))),
                 y_axis    = c(example.matrix[,2],example.matrix[,3]))

example.plot <- ggplot(example.plot.data, aes(x=x, y=y_axis, color=ball_user)) + geom_line()    
example.plot
```

produces the following graph:

[image: Simple example]

and I can analyze it (I believe) with:

```
area_under_curve = 0
for(x in min(example.matrix[,1]):max(example.matrix[,1])){
  indexes = example.matrix[,1]==x
  y.diff.array  = example.matrix[,2][indexes] - example.matrix[,3][indexes]
  pos.dif.array = y.diff.array[y.diff.array>0] 
  neg.dif.array = y.diff.array[y.diff.array<0] 
  if(length(pos.dif.array)==1){
    area_under_curve = area_under_curve + abs(pos.dif.array)
  } else {
    ## deal with overlap here
  }
  if(length(neg.dif.array)==1){
    area_under_curve = area_under_curve + abs(neg.dif.array)
  } else {
    ## deal with overlap here
  }
}
```

However, as I've highlighted in the above code, I don't have a solution if the lines overlap themselves, but have put where I think I could put code within the framework I've got at the moment. For example, let's imagine I have a graph created with:

```
example.matrix = matrix(c(0,1,2,3,2,3,4, 2,5,4,5,4,5,3, 2,2,4,6,3,2,3),nrow = 7)
example.plot.data = data.frame(x = rep(example.matrix[,1],2),
                 ball_user = c(rep("user",length(example.matrix[,2])),
                               rep("ball",length(example.matrix[,3]))),
                 y_axis    = c(example.matrix[,2],example.matrix[,3]))

 example.plot <- ggplot(example.plot.data, aes(x=x, y=y_axis, color=ball_user,  group = ball_user)) + geom_point()+geom_path()
 example.plot
```

produces:

[image]

My formula wouldn't work for this. My problem is that it's unknown how many times the ball or user line will back up on itself.

I also suspect that my solution to calculate the area between the lines for the simple graph is unnecessarily elaborate, so there's probably a more elegant solution for that that also addresses my complex example?

Or, maybe there is a way to capture the average distance for each point in the user's line from the ball's line? I fear that this would require calculating individually the shortest distance for each point in the user's line from the ball's line and thus be horrendously computationally demanding.

Comment: Are you really interested in the area between the trajectories in an x-y plot? I think in your example with "user" and "ball" it makes much more sense to look at the distance of "user" and "ball" at each timestep. This is a value you can easily integrate and self-intersecting lines are no longer a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the question to convey what I'd ideally like. I have a bad feeling that just the distance between user and ball at each x-co-ordinate could be misleading depending on how the participant deviates (e.g. going too far to the right at one moment when it slopes up). The ideal (I think) is the mean distance between the two lines, but that's more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution that depends on that you want to keep the sign of the difference. It uses the fact that you have measurements at the same `x`-values and combines that with the `auc` function from the `MESS` package which computes the area under a curve.

```
example.matrix = matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,  2,5,3,5,3,5,2,  2,2,4,6,4,2,2),nrow = 7)
x <- example.matrix[,1]
y1 <- example.matrix[,2]
y2 <- example.matrix[,3]

MESS::auc(x, y1-y2)
```

gives you a result of 3. If you want the total area (ie., throw away the sign) you can use

```
MESS::auc(x, y1-y2, absolutearea=TRUE)
```

which gives 15.

Comment: no chance you're aware of a function that would capture the average distance between lines...? I know it's a bit of a cheeky ask

Comment: If the x's are equidistant wouldn't it then just be `mean(y2-y1)` or `mean(abs(y2-y1))` or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Or you could just use `MESS::auc(x, y1-y2) / (max(x) - min(x))`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the deviation of the ball from the user, I think it would be most appriate to calculate the distance of the two lines at each timestep and then take the mean of all those distances.

The calulation of the distances is actually not so complicated:

```
calc_distances <- function(ball_x, ball_y, user_x, user_y) {
  sqrt((ball_x - user_x)^2 + (ball_y - user_y)^2) 
}
```

Let's try that with your examples. First the easy version:

```
ball_x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
ball_y <- c(2,2,4,6,4,2,2)
user_x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
user_y <- c(2,5,3,5,3,5,2)

distances <- calc_distances(ball_x, ball_y, user_x, user_y)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(ball_x, ball_y, type = 'l', col = "red")
lines(user_x, user_y, col = "blue")
plot(distances, type = 'l')
abline(h=mean(distances), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image: first example]

And the more complicated:

```
ball_x <- c(0,1,2,3,2,3,4)
ball_y <- c(2,2,4,6,3,2,3)
user_x <- c(0,1,2,3,2,3,4)
user_y <- c(2,5,4,5,4,5,3)

distances <- calc_distances(ball_x, ball_y, user_x, user_y)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(ball_x, ball_y, type = 'l', col = "red")
lines(user_x, user_y, col = "blue")
plot(distances, type = 'l')
abline(h=mean(distances), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image: second example]

Comment: The potential problem I see with this, for me at least, is that I'm not working in time, but in x,y deviations. So, looking at the first figure of mine, imagine if the user lunges to the right at the midway point - because the slope inclines at that point, the difference in y-axis between where their ball is and the user is would be quite high, even though the distance between their point and the trajectory would be relatively little (left to right, but not top to bottom). Hopefully that makes sense, and looking at my new top figure should capture the essence of the problem. ps in next comment

Comment: What your solution and problem have highlighted is that I've been going about my problem wrong! I have time stamps for each position, and for my task I should, for each time stamp, be comparing the distance between the "ball" position and the "user" position! So, your solution and comments have been really helpful! I've voted it up, but I think the other solution is more accurate for the question I've asked, whereas you've addressed the question I should have asked (but would require to present differently processed data differently to ask as you've answered it)

Comment: Glad I could help :)